# React-Redux-Form set 'error' prop and use error message as 'helperText' prop in Material-UI TextField

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, react-redux-form

Upon validation, I'd like to be able to push `error` prop the `<Control>` component, so that the MUI Textfield is red and set the `helperText` prop to the error messages instead of using the `<Errors>` component.

Here's my code and thanks in advance for the help / guidance.
        ...

```
    import { Control, Errors } from 'react-redux-form';
    import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';        

    ...

    const LoginText = props => (<TextField {...props} />);

    class MyLoginComponent extends React.PureComponent {
      render() {

        ...

        return (
        <div>
            <Control
              model="myForms.user.myLogin"
              component={LoginText}
              name="myLogin"
              label="My login"
              placeholder="myLoginFormat"
              className={classes.textField}
              required
              validators={{
                required,
                myIdFormat,
              }}
              validateOn="blur"
            />
            <Errors
              className={[classes.textField, classes.errorMsg].join(' ')}
              model="myForms.user.myLogin"
              component="p"
              show={{ touched: true, focus: false }}
              messages={{
                required: 'Enter your Login ID',
                myIdFormat: 'Please use the My ID format. Ex: myLoginFormat',
              }}
            />

          ...

          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Where is material-UI TextField? Where is your Control and Errors component? It’s really difficult to help you Without knowing inner code of these components

Comment: Hi @HemadriDasari - thanks for having a look! I updated to the code snippet with the `react-redux-form` and `material-ui` imports as well as how I call the material-ui TextField component into `Control` .

Comment: What have you tried so far and what problem did you run into? The StackOverflow community is more likely to want to help you if you describe a specific problem rather than "How do I do X?"

Comment: Hello @stone - thx for your response. Many folks on StackOverflow ask "How do I do X" and are answered with links to boilerplates, repos, codepens or snippets as many times solutions are not documented or updated in an anticipated space. So, I have questions for you. Have you used react-redux-form and material-ui? If so, how did you toggle a material-ui TextField error state upon a react-redux-form validation event?

Comment: I didn't actually downvote, but that page has a great writeup of the amount of effort good question writers put in.

Comment: Thanks for the link @stone and not downvoting. I'm aware of providing evidence of attempting to solve an issue; however, I've seen folks on this site for years who've been helped out and who have provided substantially less information than I've provided. Not that I'm justifying the lack of research I provided, nor my laziness in not providing it, I just didn't expect the reprimand, being as this was the first question I've asked in a very long time.

Comment: Please don't see it as a reprimand! It's a request for more effort and information. I think there's a great question in the making here if you spend some time on it. I have done something similar to what you're attempting and it turned out to be tricky but really satisfying in the end. I think if you put in the effort to make this a well-researched question, in the end you'll likely find your own answer and definitely learn a lot.